# MockEndpoints not working in Camel 2.14 and Spring 4.07

Tags: java, spring, junit, apache-camel

I'm trying to mock my endpoints in camel in my unit tests. I'm using Camel Enhanced Spring Test.

This is my unit class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("development")
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, FirstbirdTestExecutionListener.class,
        FlywayTestExecutionListener.class })
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:hibernate-spring.xml", "classpath:broker.xml",
        "classpath:camel/camel-commons.xml",
        "classpath:camel/firstbird-application-consumer.xml", })
@FlywayTest
@MockEndpoints("bean:applicationResponseProcessor")
@DisableJmx(false)
public class FirstBirdApplicationsTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    private static final String resourceUri = "src/test/resources/data/firstbird/";

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("context-firstbird-applications-consumer")
    protected ModelCamelContext camelContext;

    @Produce(uri = "direct:firstbird.application.service")
    private ProducerTemplate in;

    @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:out")
    private MockEndpoint mockOut;

    @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:bean:applicationResponseProcessor", context = "context-firstbird-applications-consumer")
    private MockEndpoint mock;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        FirstbirdJsonHelper.setResourceUri(resourceUri);
    }

    @Test
    public void inComingApplicationsTest() throws Exception {
        assertEquals(ServiceStatus.Started, camelContext.getStatus());

        // not wirking!
        camelContext.setTracing(true);

        DefaultExchange exchange = new DefaultExchange(camelContext);

        mock.expectedMessageCount(1);
        mockOut.expectedMessageCount(1);

        // not working
        MockEndpoint test = MockEndpoint.resolve(camelContext, "mock:bean:applicationResponseProcessor");

        camelContext.getRouteDefinition("firstbird-incomming-applications").adviceWith(camelContext,
                new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {

                    @Override
                    public void configure() throws Exception {
                        mockEndpoints("bean:applicationResponseProcessor");
                    }
                });

        exchange.getIn().setBody("GoGo Gadget Route me!");

        in.send(exchange);
        // Thread.sleep(4000);

        // not working
        List<Exchange> receivedExchanges = mock.getReceivedExchanges();
        ApplicationResponse applicationResponse = (ApplicationResponse) receivedExchanges.get(0).getIn().getBody();

        // working
        mockOut.assertIsSatisfied();
    }
}
```

This is the corresponding route:

```
<camelContext errorHandlerRef="loggingErrorHandler" id="context-firstbird-applications-consumer" trace="true" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="firstbird-incomming-applications">
        <from id="firstbird-ws-producer" uri="{{firstbird.applications.service}}"/>
        <log logName="firstbird.data.consumer.firstbird-ws-producer" loggingLevel="INFO" message="Send data to queue"/>
        <setExchangePattern pattern="InOnly"/>
        <recipientList id="webservice-recipientlist" ignoreInvalidEndpoints="true" stopOnException="false">
            <simple>activemq:${header.operationName}</simple>
        </recipientList>
        <to uri="bean:applicationResponseProcessor"/>
        <to uri="mock:out"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Basically I want to mock **bean:applicationResponseProcessor** therefore I created my MockEndpoint **mock** . Problem is it doesn't seem to get injected. I can still debug in my applicationResponseProcessor bean.

The only solution that works is using AdviceWith like so:

```
camelContext.getRouteDefinition("firstbird-incomming-applications").adviceWith(camelContext, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        mockEndpoints("bean:applicationResponseProcessor");
    }
});
```

The other problem I have is with enable tracing in my JUnit Test. Enable tracing via

```
camelContext.setTracing(true);
```

Doesn't work. I have to explicitly set Tracing in my XML file.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to mock a bean (or a call to a bean). Would Springockito work for you?

Comment: hey I would have to look into that. Basically I want to know if this is a bug or if I'm doing something wrong with my camel setup

Comment: When you setup the camelContext.setTracing(true), the routes are installed, so it doesn't work.

Comment: you mean I cannot use setTracing(true) and @MockEndpoints at the same time?